# Need help creating Add-in that uses custom back ground for powerpoint master slide

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I am working with C# to do an Excel add-in that creates a few reports slides using Power Point Interop.

The problem I am having is when using code like this

```
Presentation.SlideMaster.Background.Fill.UserPicture(@"C\whatever path\picture.jpg");
```

This works great on my developing machine but when I publish the add in and give the installer .exe to the user it does not work because the add-in is looking for the picture.jpg in C\whatever path\picture.jpg".

How do I solve this without having to manually add the picture.jpg to whatever path the code is calling?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the picture in the startup path?

Comment: is in a resource folder included when I publish the add in along with the .vsto file. After installation the start-up path points to where the .vsto file is. I think the problem is that the path in the code starts with c\and a sequence of folders including my user name. How do I make it so it searches around the .vsto location?

Comment: assuming you can calculate the path from the startup folder         string path = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "path to resource folder" + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + PictureBox.jpg;

Comment: I tried it but I still have to determine user name. I don't know how many different users it might go trough. I could keep it simple and install from c\ but the users wont have admin rights to do anything from c\. They most likely install from user documents or something similar. if I calculate from System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath I still have to dynamically find out user name and whatever might vary along the way. I am surprise I cant drop the image in Properties.Resource.resx and have the compiler figure it out.

Comment: Why not make it so the resource file is a folder in the startup directory like nearly every other program out there?

Comment: Install to C:\Users\Public\Documents (or probably better, wherever the PUBLIC environment variable points + \Documents\YourDirectory)